# Python Flask return video file OR JSON data using curl

Tags: python, flask, curl, httprequest

I am using a python flask swagger server for my api.  I wish to create an API that can return some json data OR a video file.

My function definition is:

```
from flask import send_file

def my_function():
    some_case = True #This could be False
    try:
        some_json = {
            "Data1": "Blah",
            "Data2": "0Blah"
        }

        if some_case:
            return some_json, 200
        else:
            return send_file('/home/video_file.mp4')

    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

I am using curl to call my API like so:

```
curl -X GET "http://0.0.0.0:8888/MyFunction"
{
  "Data1": "Blah",
  "Data2": "0Blah"
}
```

But when I call it when **some_case=False** and hence the video file will download I get:

```
curl -X GET "http://0.0.0.0:8888/MyFunction"
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

And I then have to specify an output file like so in order to actually download it:

```
curl -X GET "http://0.0.0.0:8888/MyFunction" --output my_video.mp4
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 6575k  100 6575k    0     0   642M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  642M
```

How can I call this API using curl without knowing what the return is going to be? (json or video file)